# Algorithm to determine "visual clarity", or pixelation of an image

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick

Is there any such way to determine how much an image could be enlarged until it is considered "out of focus"?

**A practical example** (and the problem I'm trying to solve):

I have an image saved at several different sizes, say 500x500, 250x250, and 120x120. I want to serve the most efficient image, but also the most clear. If a user was to request an image at 125x125, obviously increasing the 120x120 image to accommodate would not only be most efficient but most likely would not cause any apparent pixelation.

Yet, if a user was to request an image at 180x180, it may be more efficient to increase the 120x120 image, but most likely would render a blurry image. In this case, I would want to shrink the 250x250 image.

Obviously the "clarity" of an image can be relative and vary from eye to eye, as well as image to image, but I'm wondering if there is any sort of algorithm or function to determine a "pixelation index" of sorts...Thanks!

Note: using PHP & ImageMagick for image manipulations, so any answer in that realm would be great...

**For Clarification:** I'm not exactly looking for a *solution* to my above example. I'm looking for an answer to the original question: `is there an algorithm that could possibly determine how "pixelated" a blown up image is`...The above problem is just a practical example of how such algorithm could be useful.

Comment: always shrink. blowing up will always produce a lower quality result than shrinking a larger original. better to remove unwanted data than try to produce data that isn't there to begin with.

Comment: @MarcB is actually very right. Always shrinking will ensure that you get the best image quality, and the increased size should be negligible at best (considering you're not willing to blow up a MUCH smaller image, which would reduce the size significantly).

Comment: Ok, maybe so...But, an impractical example would be this: would you rather shrink a 250x250 image to 121x121, or increase a 120x120 up...the image quality in this case should be absolutely negligible, but the server load would be much lower...

Comment: The server load to determine that using an algorithm would be very much higher than just shrinking in the first place, using an algorithm like you've described. Plus, you're caching your rendered images (*right*?), so it shouldn't be a one-time thing anyway.

Comment: Yes & Yes, your right...however, doing the heavy work on upload of the image and saving my so-called "pixelation-index" as a static number would cause no additional work during the image requests (just simple int comparisons)...also, even though the images are cached, I'm still dealing with users requesting "odd" dimensions

Comment: Why not use a dynamic thumbnail script that would serve up the exact size you want, and cache it for future requests?

Comment: This could lead to too much load in my scenario...Nonetheless, thanks for the suggestion but I'm not looking for solutions to my problem, but rather an answer to the question. Sorry for the confusion, I updated my post to accommodate.

Comment: Any such 'how "pixelated" is a blown up image' algorithm is an estimation of visual perception and depend on factors such as pixel size (/density). It doesn't necessarily have to have to be computationally expensive, if it's acceptable for it to be off-the-mark sometimes

Answer (score 1):

You could do a grey-scale sobel edge detection filter on the image, and sum up the pixel values of the edges;then average this summation against the number of pixels ( SumOfEdges/(width*height)). That would tell you the "edginess" of the image. This could only be used to compare images type.

This is my sobel opencl filter kernel

```
const sampler_t sampler = CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP_TO_EDGE |
CLK_FILTER_NEAREST;
kernel void
sobel_grayscale(read_only image2d_t src, write_only image2d_t dst)
{
int x = get_global_id(0);
int y = get_global_id(1);

float4 p00 = read_imagef(src, sampler, (int2)(x - 1, y - 1));
float4 p10 = read_imagef(src, sampler, (int2)(x, y - 1));
float4 p20 = read_imagef(src, sampler, (int2)(x + 1, y - 1));
float4 p01 = read_imagef(src, sampler, (int2)(x - 1, y));
float4 p21 = read_imagef(src, sampler, (int2)(x + 1, y));
float4 p02 = read_imagef(src, sampler, (int2)(x - 1, y + 1));
float4 p12 = read_imagef(src, sampler, (int2)(x, y + 1));
float4 p22 = read_imagef(src, sampler, (int2)(x + 1, y + 1));

float4 gx = -p00 + p20 + 2.0f * (p21 - p01)-p02 + p22;

float4 gy = -p00 - p20 +2.0f * (p12 - p10) +p02 + p22;

float gs_x = 0.3333f * (gx.x + gx.y + gx.z);
float gs_y = 0.3333f * (gy.x + gy.y + gy.z);
float g = native_sqrt(gs_x * gs_x + gs_y * gs_y);
write_imagef(dst, (int2)(x, y), (float4)(g,g,g, 1.0f));
}
```

Comment: thanks, edge detection looks promising, I'll make up some tests over the next couple days to see if I can get a working model

Comment: @fiveDust nope...realized it was simply above my brain's processing power (for now)...I do know there are some services that do similar impressive processing on images such as https://www.instartlogic.com/technology/smartvision unfortunately its not open source, but worth checking out

Comment: @anson thanks for coming back. Have you ever tried Imagick's identify ... identify -verbose filename.jpg | grep Quality ?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't do exactly what you asked, but I think it achieves what you want. Writing an algorithm to quantify how pixellated an image is would be non-trivial, and it would definitely be image-format-specific (e.g., **only** work for PNG images), and I really don't think it's necessary to achieve what you want.

So, for the sake of this example, let's assume all of your images are perfectly square (modifying this to take into account non-square images is fairly trivial):

Suppose you have a list of source images you can resize from, as well as a "result size" - say 500 pixels by 500 pixels. You might do something like this:

```
$resultSize = 500;
$bestRatio = PHP_INT_MAX;
$bestURL = "";

foreach($sourceImageURLs as $url)
{
    $size = getimagesize($url);
    $size = $size[0];

    $ratio = min($resultSize, $size) / max($resultSize, $size);

    if($ratio < $bestRatio)
    {
        $bestRatio = $ratio;
        $bestURL = $url;
    }
}

/*
 * We've now found the image closest to our desired size. All we need
 * to do is resize the image at the URL in $bestURL to $resultSize, and
 * we're done.
 */
```

I don't think I would worry about the "most efficient" image - scaling a 100x100 image up to 200x200 versus scaling a 300x300 image down to 200x200 is going to give you two images which are **very** similar in size (especially if you use some good compression tool, like PNGOUT or etc.). I would just scale from the source image closest to the desired size.

Comment: Thanks for this, although what this is accomplishing is just finding the image closest to the requested size...The solution I'm looking for deals with any impractical case possible...Also, your bottom paragraph I disagree with, its not about "final size" its about the server having to load a large image VS a small image and what quality will be lost.

Comment: Ex) in your example I could have a 500x500 image and a 100x100 image. If the requested size is 280x280, the "closest" image is the smaller one, but that would most definitely become poor quality

Comment: Right - your question doesn't really make sense. Are you trying to minimize file size, or maximize visual clarity? The former doesn't make sense unless you're willing to sacrifice a lot of visual quality. Otherwise, the savings is very negligible. If you want the latter, then you should be doing what others have suggested and just *always shrink*.

Comment: Im looking for an algorithm that could determine pixelation...the file size would actually be irrelevant to the algorithm, I only bring that portion into discussion as a practical example of how such an algorithm would be useful

Comment: Then why say *"and the problem I'm trying to solve"*? If it's just some esoteric example, and the algorithm will really be used for something else, then my answer would be entirely different. If that really is the problem you're trying to solve, though, then I would recommend another approach (namely, always shrinking).

Comment: `Is there any such way to determine how much an image could be enlarged until it is considered "out of focus"?` Thats the question and I think its quite clear. The example is a real-world case in which the algorithm would be used.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the algorithm of this **"[Duplicate Image Finder](http://www.catpa.ws/php-duplicate-image-finder/)"** to compare the fingerprint of your good quality image with the fingerprint of its low quality twin. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Image quality is entirely subjective and depends largely on the complexity of the original image. If your image was of a white cat in a snow storm (basically, just white) then the subjective quality of a 500x500 image will be identical whether you achieved it by reducing a 1000x1000 image or by increasing from a 100x100 image.

But all things being equal, you can assume that the higher resolution image will reduce to a better quality than the lower resolution will enlarge to.

So off the top of my head, you could reduce the larger picture to the target size and then use that as a metric (an ideal) for assessing the quality of the enlarged smaller picture (how different is pixel 7 on row 9 from the same pixel in the ideal image, etc.). This comparison could be made of all the pixels or from sample points within the images. The resulting "outness" could then be averaged and used as an indication of the enlarged picture's quality.